# Como copiar o script rodando para uma outra pasta em Python?

Tags: python, script, terminal

Fiz um script em Python que executa alguns comandos no terminal, e quero que ele se mova para uma outra pasta.

Tentei usar o `cp teste.py minha_pasta/teste.py`, mas não funciona. Este é meu código:

```
def exec_commands(args):

    data = args

    for f in data:

        if f[:2] == 'cd':

            if f[3:] == '~':
                print(os.environ['HOME'])
                os.chdir(os.environ['HOME'])

            else:
                os.chdir(f[3:])

        if len(f) > 0:
            cmd = subprocess.Popen(f[:], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE )
            output_bytes = cmd.stdout.read()
            output_str = str(output_bytes, "utf-8")


exec_commands(["mkdir minha_pasta", "cp teste.py minha_pasta/teste.py"])
```

Comment: E qual o propósito/necessidade de fazer isto para o seu projeto"? Está me parecendo um [problema XY](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/499/3635)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se o intuito é fazer o script se autocopiar use o método [`copy()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy) da biblioteca [`shutil`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html).

```
from shutil import copy

#Nesse exemplo foi criada previamente uma pasta chamada "nova_pasta"

print("#" * 30)
print("Esse script irá se autocopiar!")
print("#" * 30)

copy(__file__,"./nova_pasta/")
```

Funcionando no [Repli.it](https://replit.com/@Augusto-Vasques/Replicar#main.py):